# AWS SNS SMS failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to send SMS via Amazon SNS, but since yesterday they are failing, I see a delivery rate of 0% in the AWS Console. As I understand, I would have to pay 29$ upfront to report a failing service.
Is there a possibility to get via CloudWatch the reason for the failed SMS service, or is there another method to complain to Amazon?

Comment: Using AWS support would save you considerable time, which is probably worth more than $29.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein still, I don't see why I have to pay support for a service where the error seems to be on the vendor's side

Comment: @Wolfgang What was the outcome of this? Was it really AWS' fault?

Answer (score 3):

Since yesterday, the messages have completely stopped coming so you might have reached the SNS SMS spend limit for your account. By default it is 1 USD for a AWS account in a AWS region. You can check Delivery Status logs which might say 'No Quota Left for Account'.You should get your limit increased with limit increase case for which you do not have to pay 29 dollars.

But in future if you want to prevent this i.e. if you want to get notified earlier before you reach the actual SMS Spend Limit for your account so that limit can be increased before hand. In this way you would not face SMS delivery issues due to limit being reached. You can create a CloudWatch Alarm on your SMSMonthToDateSpentUSD metric.

Please have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-HdLf_lizI